# DIV to inherit height of all elements inside

Tags: css, html, height

I have a DIV that will be containing a product's information. This DIV is within a PHP for argument, so for each product this DIV will be created containing it's information.

The problem I encounter is that the DIV shows very small. However, all items inside the div are showing, but the DIV's height is minimal.

How must I force the DIV to inherit the total height of all the products inside it?

Here is my DIV:

```
.cartItem {
border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
display: block;
padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: It will inherit the height of what's inside, unless what's inside is being floated. In that case, you need to clear your floats.

Comment: can you add an image to show how it looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
Overflow: hidden;
```

does the trick...